# Scipy ODR not compatible with fsolve?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to solve specific points of an `ODR` function, so far I've used:

```
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, RealData
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

me = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
my = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

def func(beta, x):
    y = beta[0]+beta[1]*x+beta[2]*x**3
    return y

modata = RealData(me, my)
model = Model(func)

odr = ODR(modata, model, [0,0,0])
odr.set_job(fit_type=0)
output = odr.run()

mam = fsolve(func, 5, args=(output.beta))
```

I get:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

I think this is because `beta` acts as indices within the function.

I tried redefining `func` to take more than one variable as `beta`, but I can't get `ODR` to work when I do this.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fsolve` is meant to find the roots of `func`. You have to give it a starting estimate, though, that is a valid parameter to the function. You can't pass in `5` for the `beta` parameter, though. `beta` needs to be an iterable with at least three elements (since you're evaluating `beta[0]`, `beta[1]`, and `beta[2]`).

If you do `fsolve(func, [5,5,5], args=(output.beta))`, the function will run, and it outputs a root of `[0, 0, 0]` (which is clearly a correct root since `func([0, 0, 0], x)` will always return `0` regardless of the value of `x`)

Comment: Oh, doi. Thanks for that. I have some more questions regarding what I was trying to use it for but I'll post another question for that.